# Activity is an instance of MainFragmentListener, is it true?

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, instanceof

I'm wondering, how it is possible.
I have MainActivty and MainFragment with listener: MainFragmentListener.
Of course I implemented this listener as inteface in MainActivity.
Now I'm trying to understand this:

```
if (context instanceof MainFragmentListener)
```

It always true, how it is possible ? MainActivity isn't instance of MainFragmentListener.
MainFragmentListener is a just interface, not object!

MainFragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof MainFragmentListener) {
        mListener = (MainFragment.MainFragmentListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

public interface MainFragmentListener {
    void xx();
    void yy();
}
```

activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        MainFragment.MainFragmentListener{  

public void xx(){
     abc
 };
public void yy(){
abc2
 };

}
```

Comment: `instanceof` checks all inherited types, not just classes.

Comment: anyway, Activity is higher in the hierarchy than the fragment interface

Comment: Also `context` can only be an Activity here, not a Fragment. You can define as many interfaces as you want on a Activity. `instanceof` won't care

Comment: i edited, of course, is Activity here, so Activity is highter in the hierarchy than fragment interface

Comment: It doesn't matter where you wrote the interface definition. It could be in a separate `MainFragmentListener.java` file...

Comment: ok, but Activity can't be still instance of interface :)

Comment: But it is! `implements MainFragment.MainFragmentListener`... I think you should research how `instanceof` really works. It is not **only** checking classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Activity is higher in the hierarchy than the fragment interface

So? Assuming that Fragment is assigned to MainActivity, then `context instanceof` will be true for

- The class itself  - MainActivity.
- Any interface you defined on that class (regardless where the definition of the interface is written)

  - NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
  - MainFragment.MainFragmentListener

**As well as** each class **and interface** [in the hierarchy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity)

`public class AppCompatActivity 
extends FragmentActivity implements AppCompatCallback, TaskStackBuilder.SupportParentable, ActionBarDrawerToggle.DelegateProvider`

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
                   ↳    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `instanceof` also checking if a class implements an interface. You can read from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html):

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You
>   can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance
>   of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular
>   interface.

Though I think the `instanceof` operator name is a bit misleading.